# Why is my state not being updated in my callbacks?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to understand the state in React, having a background with Vue.js.

I'm building a login which fetches a JWT-token, then stores the token in a global store so we can use it for subsequent API-calls. I'm using an [axios interceptor](https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors) to resolve the token from the store. However, the token is always an old version/from previous render.

I've read about [the React lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) but this function is not used in the rendering. It's used as a callback. I understand that setting the state is async. I've tried wrapping the interceptor in a `useEffect(.., [tokenStore.token])` and using setTimeout(). I feel like I'm missing something.

Why is my state not being updated in my callbacks? Am I going about this in an non-idiomatic way?

Usage:

```
<button onPress={() => loginWithToken('abc')}>
  Sign In
</button>
```

User hook:

```js
export function useUserState() {
  const api = useApi();

  function loginWithToken(token) {
    tokenState.setToken(token);

    api
      .request('get', 'currentUser')
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch((errors) => {
        console.log(errors);
      });
  }
}
```

The api:

```js
export default function useApi(hasFiles = false) {
  const tokenState = useTokenState();
  const client = axios.create(/*...*/);

  client.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    config.headers!.Authorization = tokenState.token
      ? `Bearer ${tokenState.token}`
      : '';
    return config;
  });
  // ...
}
```

Token store using [hookstate](https://hookstate.js.org/):

```js
const tokenState = createState({
  token: null,
});

export function useTokenState() {
  const state = useState(tokenState);

  return {
    token: state.token.get(),
    setToken: (token: string | null) => {
      console.log('setToken: ' + token);
      state.set({ token });
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: Where have you called `createState`?

Comment: It's in the same file as the useTokenState. Left it out to minimize the code but I'll add it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by updating the defaults instead:

```
setToken: token => {
  apiClient.defaults.headers.Authorization = token
    ? `Bearer ${token}`
    : undefined;

  // ...
```